# How to compute my integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I'm trying to compute the following integral

```
integrand = (-2 (Log[2] - Log[1/t + t])^2)/(-1 + t^2)
```

Numerically integrating it gives the expected result

```
1/2*NIntegrate[integrand, {t, 0, 1}]
=> 1.0518
N[7/8*Zeta[3]]
=> 1.0518
```

However when I try to integrate it symbolically I get

```
1/2*Integrate[integrand, {t, 0, 1}]
=> 1/16 (\[Pi] (I \[Pi] + Log[4]) (\[Pi] + I Log[64]) + 14 Zeta[3])
N[%]
=> -0.658472 + 3.06993 I
```

It is interesting that Mathematica returns the correct result `14/16 Zeta[3]` as part of its solution, but in addition it returns some strange imaginary terms, which I couldn't get rid of. What can I do so that Mathematica will compute this integral correctly?

Update: My version of Mathematica:

`11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)`

Comment: On 11.1.0, I get the same result from both ways. Btw, the result has a negative sign.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the sign in the integrand. It fixed it now.

Comment: With `11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)` using either `1/2*Integrate[integrand, {t, 0, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]` or `1/2*Integrate[integrand, {t, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < t < 1]` they evaluate to `-((7*Zeta[3])/8)`. Note your "correction" is not the negative of the original `integrand`

Comment: This seems to have shown up in 11.0.1, since version 11 gives the result `(7 Zeta[3])/8` directly. Can you try `Integrate[Log[(2 t)/(1 + t^2)]^2/(1 - t^2), {t, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: @J.M. I tried your suggested integral and the result was `7/8*Zeta[3]` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify a real-ish path:

```
1/2*Integrate[integrand, {t, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < t < 1]
(*  -((7 Zeta[3])/8)  *)
```

Or:

```
res = 1/2*Integrate[integrand, {t, 0, 1/2, 1}];  (* verrry looong expressssion *)
N[res, 16]
(* -1.0517997902646450 + 0.*10^-17 I *)
```

Comment: `res//Simplify` evaluates to `-((7*Zeta[3])/8)` as expected

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, I didn't try that.  It still takes a long time to evaluate, so I wasn't that keen to follow up on it. -- But, wow, it simplifies really fast!

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(*  "11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"  *)

integrand = (2 (Log[2] - Log[1/t + t])^2)/(-1 + t^2);

intN = 1/2*NIntegrate[integrand, {t, 0, 1}]

(*  -1.0518  *)
```

This is the negative of the result that you show. However, a `Plot` shows that the integral should be negative.

```
Plot[integrand, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Finding the Cauchy principal value

```
int = 1/2*Integrate[integrand, {t, 0, 1}, 
   PrincipalValue -> True]

(*  -((7 Zeta[3])/8)  *)

int == intN

(*  True  *)
```